# Pagination Selected Limits gets reset when clicks next / previous button

Tags: javascript, php, pagination

The table result filter by limit gets reset when the pagination action done. If I select limit 10 from the dropdown and click next, the limit automatically reset to 5 which is the default

```
<?php
        $limit  = isset($_POST['limit-records']) ? $_POST['limit-records'] : 5;
        $page =  isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;

        if($_SESSION['access'] == "user"){
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM `enquiry list` WHERE `designated_staff` = ? ORDER BY `enquiry list`.`ID` DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
          $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
          $result->execute([$_SESSION['user']]);

        }else{
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM `enquiry list` ORDER BY `enquiry list`.`ID` DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
          $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
          $result->execute();
        }

        $total = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `enquiry list`");
        $total->execute();
        $count = $total->rowCount();
        $pages = ceil($count / $limit);
        $prev = $page - 1;
        $next = $page + 1;
    ?>
```

Pagination Drop Down

```
<form method="post">
  <select class="form-control" name="limit-records" id="limit-records">
    <option disabled = "disabled"  selected = "selected">Result Views</option>
      <?php foreach([5,10,15,20,25] as $limit):?>
        <option <?php if(isset($_POST['limit-records']) && $_POST['limit-records']==$limit) echo "selected" ?> value="<?php echo $limit; ?>"><?php echo $limit; ?></option>
      <?php endforeach;?>
  </select>
</form>
```

JQuery Submit

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#limit-records").change(function(){
          $("form").submit();
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

limits variable should be GET not POST like that

```
$limit  = isset($_GET['limit-records']) ? $_GET['limit-records'] : 5;
```

change your page logic

Comment: here I am taking the limit value using JQuery post

Comment: any thing related to pagination have to be GET, append the limit with the page id

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you got this pagination logic from [here](https://github.com/durgesh-sahani/bootstrap-pagination-php-mysql/blob/master/index.php)

Every time you access the pagination links, the posted limit variable is lost and therefore resets to the default value. The way I solved this is by converting the pagination links to html forms. That way, you can redirect with the pages intact and still pass on the current limit value using a hidden input.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
                <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
              <ul class="pagination">
                
                <li class="page-item <?php echo $page == 1 ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>">
                    <form id="pagination-button"action="viewRecords.php?page=<?= $Previous;?>" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" id="page-itemlink" name = limit-records value = "<?php echo $limit; ?>">
                    <button type ="submit"class="page-link"  aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo; Previous</span>
                </button>
            </form>
                </li>

                <?php for($i = 1; $i<= $pages; $i++) : ?>
                <li class="page-item ">
                    <form id="pagination-button" action="viewRecords.php?page=<?= $i;?>" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" id="page-itemlink" name = limit-records value = "<?php echo $limit; ?>">
                    <button type="submit" class="page-link" ><?= $i; ?></button>
                </form>
                </li>
            <?php endfor; ?>
                
                <li class="page-item <?php echo $page == $pages ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>">
                    <form id="pagination-button" action="viewRecords.php?page=<?= $Next;?>" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" id="page-itemlink" name = limit-records value = "<?php echo $limit; ?>">    
                    <button type="submit" class="page-link"  aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">Next &raquo;</span>
                </button>
            </form>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```